# Como puedo mostrar un mensaje "redirectAttributes" sin que se borren los datos de mi formulario

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Tengo un formulario el cual cuando le doy al boton tipo "submit" me envia los datos al controlador y me valida que si el correo con el cual me quiero crear un nuevo perfil existe en base de datos, entonces me muestra un mensaje de error,lo que necesito es que al hacer esto no se pierdan los datos que ya ingrese previamente, por ejemplo mi formulario se ve asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al darle al boton me limpia el formulario y me muestra el mensaje :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Precisamente lo que no quiero que pase, este es mi metodo que valida si el correo existe y me agrega el mensaje si existe el correo:

```
@PostMapping("/save")
public String save (@RequestParam(value = "passwordNewUser") String passwordNewUser,@Validated Account acc, Model model,RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    Account searchUser = new Account();
    searchUser = serviceAccount.findByAccountemail(acc.getAccountemail());
    if(searchUser == null) {
        acc.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(passwordNewUser));
        serviceAccount.save(acc);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("successMessage", "");
    }else {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("errorMessage", "");
        return "redirect:/new";
    }
    
    return "redirect:/login";
}
```